# ALM Quality Center : Need to secure New created defect according to Predefind filter by Group

Tags: hp-alm

I am working on HP QUALITY CENTER v11 ALM I create a New Defect on the project from the HMI of ALM

PreRequisites :

The project is “Domain” and “Project-01”

I created two user fields “BG_USER_12” et “BG_USER_02” with a list of String

I created some User Groups with some “data-hiding” (access from the Customize -> Groups and Permissions -> Data-hiding ) Filters are like BG_USER_12 == “APP__SPECIAL” (they are generic because of "*")

When I launched the application ALM for a user in this group, the data-hiding works properly : I only see the defects filtered with the data-hiding corresponding to “APP__SPECIAL”

But, the problem happens now :
When I create a "new defect", when I select from BG_USER_12 a value , which is not included in the filter “APP__SPECIAL” ,I have the right to do it, ALM creates the Defect (without checking if the criteria of the filter matches or not), ALM display the Defect (even if it does not match the filter criteria),

•   If I click on it , it says “The object does not exist”

•   If a refresh the display, it disappears

•   If I get log to ALM with TDAdmin for example, I can see the defects has been correctly added to the Project

Questions:

1. Is it a bug ?
2. How can I secure the modification of a field , where some data-hiding are set in (Customize -> Groups and Permissions -> Data-hiding) , not to be chosen from the not acceptable values.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the `Bug_FieldCanChange` function on the workflow (*under defect module script*), and write how you want it behave.

This function gets the field name and the new value (the current/old value can be found that `way:Bug_Fields("BG_USER_12").Value`).

And you can just manipulate it as you want, you can through a `masgbox`saying it is not aloud, or you can leave the field unchanged.
the *DefaultRes* var is a true/false determine whether the field can be changed or not.